# how an object not affected by other object

Tags: unity-game-engine

Hello i'm trying build a game i have a problem, i have an object i put a ball over it now when i set the object move up and down the ball can't let the object to move up, i want the ball not effect the object and go with it up or down or right or left

```
public class PipeController : MonoBehaviour {

Rigidbody2D rb;
[SerializeField] float speed;
[SerializeField] float maxY;
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    PipeMove();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}
void PipeMove()
{
    rb.velocity = new Vector2(speed, maxY);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a rigid body to the ball. The object can't move because it has an static object above.